# How can you find parts for a discontinued bike - in this case, a 2004 Specialized mountain bike

Tags: parts

I'm looking for the rear shock link for a 2004 Specialized FSR XC. Specialized doesn't have them; and so far I haven't been able to find that link anywhere!

Can anyone guide me in the right direction in finding parts for discontinued bicycles? Where should I be looking for parts?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]. I see you've taken the [tour]. Since you're asking a question the next thing to do is check out [ask]. And please, DON'T SHOUT AT US!

Comment: Good luck -- finding the part if its specific to a nearly 15 year old bike is going to be tough, short of having another one for parts. Do you have a specialized part number or something? If its part of the shock, you could also ask the shock manufacturer.

Comment: I suggest fabricating a replacement. These bikes appear to have a custom sized link. Another approach would be to Google the make of shock and see what comes up. Various internet boards show finding a new link is hard.

Comment: Take it out, fit a length of steel instead and ride it as a hard tail.

Comment: You may try posting want ads on craigslist (or something similar) in your area.  Someone may have an old brokey one they are willing to part out.

Comment: Edited question to make it less specific and more generic for this stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

First, try looking for a "scrap" FSR to salvage the linkage from.

Second, BETD have produced aftermarket suspension components for various Specialized, GT, Kona etc designs. They might not have the item you need in stock, but they should still have the files and machinery necessary to make one for you, at a price. http://www.mountainbikecomponents.co.uk/specialized-fsr-04-06-linkage

If you can find some engineering workshop near you, they might be able to copy your damaged linkage. A basic non-adjustable linkage should be achievable using any 3-axis mill.